# Which tool to use to perform stress testing in a server waiting for custom XMPP IQ Stanzas?

Tags: testing, xmpp, stress-testing, tsung

I have an application that receives some custom XMPP IQ stanzas and process these.
I would like to make a stress test on it, to see how many users it can support, I searched it and found Tsung.
I downloaded the package for Ubuntu and tried to install, but when I run it on the command line, I have the following error:

> Config file /home/user/.tsung/tsung.xml doesn't exist, aborting !

I tried also to download the compressed file and to compile, as explained [here](http://vidorsolutions.blogspot.com/2010/12/load-testing-ejabberd-xmpp-server-with.html), but I also got an error when I run the "make" command.

Do you know any other software I could use to perform the stress test?

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 0):

Has for the error, I add the same problem has you did. And of easy resolution if that is the only one.
One would imagine that the debian package would create the /home/$USER/.tsung dir but that is not true.
To solve that problem you would only need to create the directory on your home project

```
cd ~
mkdir .tsung
```

place a the file of the test (tsung.xml) in it, and run tsung start again

---

Has for another software I had used jab_simul, C software with a few year and with little to none documentation, But I was able to use it by following [this directions](http://www.ejabberd.im/benchmark) But this may not solve your problem cause unless you change the code, it does not provide any custom stanzas, at least that I know off.

Comment: Hi!
Sorry, I can't test it because this project has finished and therefore the environment no longer exists. For this reason I can't mark as answered :(

Answer (score 0):

Tsung is good chooice and use it's jabber request with type=raw to test your custom IQ stanzas.